# Pros and cons of setting super admin in users table

Tags: permissions

I'm structuring a [RBAC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Role-based_access_control) in a Web system. My database tables looks like:

- **actions**

  - id
  - name
- **resources**

  - id
  - name
- **permissions**

  - id
  - action_id
  - resource_id
- **roles**

  - id
  - name
- **permission_role**

  - permission_id
  - role_id
- **users**

  - id
  - role_id
  - is_super_admin

The roles are dynamics (users can CRUD them) so if I seed "super admin" role it could be deleted in future. In this way, the first solution that I found was to create a boolean column "is_super_admin" directly in users table and seed the first user (me) with it as true.

What would be possibly the advantages and disadvantages of setting the super admin (the user that can do anything) in users table?